# JOSE Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]

Tags: node.js, npm, jose

I keep on getting this error since I installed this module yesterday with `jose` package from `npm` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose)

```js
 Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /home/dev/projects/api/node_modules/jose/package.json
at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:290:9)
at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:513:3)
at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:432:36)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:472:31)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:867:27)
at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:61:29)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dev/projects/api/src/utils/utils.ts:5:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10) {
code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

**Environment:**

- `jose` version: [e.g. v3.5.1]
- affected runtime is: [e.g. Node.js 14.15.4 `npm` version 6.14.11
- Ubuntu 18.04

My tscongig:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "src/types/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Possibly related dependencies I use:

```js
{"typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.12.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  },
```

I have not gotten any work-around yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out solution [here](https://github.com/panva/jose/issues/142#issuecomment-758469721)

> This is an import issue I have really had for more than 24 hours. Anyway, I just Found out you have latest updates two days ago with different import style and other changes. Fixing the imports seem to help me.

and other key object name updated so I have downgraded the package to `2.0.3` temporarily

Comment: Besides downgraded to 2.0.3, is there other solution for jose 3.11.0?